# What is the semantic contribution of 配 in 配慮? Or in general, what is 配 really?

Tags: meaning, kanji

I encountered 配慮 in my word list. Understanding how 慮 contributes to its meaning (which is "consideration") is not very difficult to grasp considering that 遠慮 occurs commonly in daily life. But when I try to associate 配 with 配る and 心配 (and adding 配慮 to the mix), I feel that this kanji does not seem to have a "unifying meaning" associated to it, unlike 木 (although, it might be an unfair comparison because it's a 象形文字). I understand that it's hopeless trying to unify meanings associated to certain kanjis like 占める and 占う. But what about 配？

Comment: Are you familiar with the expression こころをくばる?

Comment: This is the first time I heard it, and it looks very figurative to me :)

Comment: By the way, ここるをくばる and 心配する have different meanings, right?

Comment: @Leebo Did you mean [気を配る](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B0%97%E3%82%92%E9%85%8D%E3%82%8B)?

Comment: @naruto no I did mean こころをくばる. It's in the 大辞林 definition of 配慮, for instance. https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%85%8D%E6%85%AE They do mean similar things, from what I can tell. In either case, it lends insight into what 配 is doing in 配慮.

Comment: @Leebo, yeah it says in the other dictionary: また、「配慮」と置き換えうる和語には「気配り」「心配り」「心遣い」などがある。But then, I don't have any experience using these words, so...

Comment: @naruto I just realized that 気配する exists. This does not share any meaning with 気を配る right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

配 is commonly encapsulated in English with "distribute", but you might also capture much of it with the word "**allot**", in the sense of allotting each its due. So 配慮 would give you "allotting-consideration", or more idiomatically, "paying consideration".

Source: Comparing all the kanji compounds for 配 in the スーパー大辞林.